# HTML file displays as text. Why?

Tags: html, xampp

I'm not using PHP. XAMPP finds my .html file just fine, BUT it doesn't process the HTML. Instead, it displays the file as text.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if you have saved the file with the option (SAVE as text FILE)
for example if you have saved your file as abc.html then it would become abc.html.txt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmaFq.png)

so it is supposed to be a html file but it will become text file